# Why does MinGW/MSys change the binary path?

Tags: windows, cmd, mingw, msys

I'm using Mingw to build a C/C++ project. This project has makefiles beyond my comprehension, and relies on a custom and quite sophisticated toolchain to compile it. It's quite convenient to have GNU tools available on Windows, especially from Windows's cmd shell, but while invoking the tools (make in particular), MinGW seems to change my PATH around.

Cmd does it normally:

```
echo %PATH% > ... c:\Apps\msys\bin ... (from cmd)
```

but msys changes this address to :

```
echo $PATH > ... /usr/bin ...
```

in msys, even when I print the PATH from a makefile. As a result, make complains that it can't find commands like make, uname, echo, you name it (no pun intended).

Strangely, I managed to get this environment working ages ago without a hitch, but this is the first time I remember seeing this path problem. How can I get MinGW/msys to correctly point to its executables?

Comment: Have you changed a config file. Sounds like you have set the PATH somewhere. look in .bashrc .profile /etc/profile /etc/bash.bashrc I always used the bash shell in an xterm (not cmd), I never say any unexplained problems like this. Try `/usr/bin/find / -mount  -print0 | /bin/xargs -0 /bin/grep PATH | /usr/bin/less`

Comment: I haven't touched the config files. Upon closer inspection, it seems that make is complaining because the makefiles modify path, and there seems to be both Windows-style paths and Linux-style paths clashing. Again, I had this working out of the box not that long ago. Methinks there were some incompatible updates done in the meantime.

Comment: The problem may be cmd. If make uses sh or bash as a shell then the set environment variable is not persistent. Make uses a new shell for each command and the set only affects the shell and sub shells, never parent shells. But I think cmd does thinks differently, I think it sets it globally. Tell make to use sh as a shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

richard has a point - there were two different shells fighting over environment variables (not to mention running msys) and so each parsed its own and the system's environment variables differently.

Also make sure that variables defined in your user or system environment are properly written - Windows likes "C:\foo\bar" style paths, but Msys treats them as "/c/foo/bar".